# удаление пробела в php

Tags: php

я загружаю данные из xml в базу SQL

при удалении пробела не удаляется как мне быть помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

```
  $TYPE=$TICKET->TYPE;
  $x=$TICKET->SYSTEM->attributes();
  $bso_id=$x['bso_id'];
  $id=$x['id'];
  str_replace(" ", "", trim($session=$x['session']));

echo $sql="INSERT INTO TICKET ([TYPE],[bso_id],[id],[session])
      VALUES ('".$TYPE."','".$bso_id."','".$id."','".$session."')";
      $conn->execute($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы не сохраняете результат обработки строки в переменную

```
$session = str_replace(" ", "", trim($x['session']));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @delphi, отметьте ответ, решенным. Рядом с ответом `etki` галочка.